# AWS Sam CLI Error: Failed to parse template: unacceptable character #x0000: special characters are not allowed in "<unicode string>", position 0

Tags: python, windows, docker, yaml, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to run a docker image using the 'sam local start-api' command in windows command prompt and I am getting this Error: Failed to parse template: unacceptable character #x0000: special characters are not allowed in "", position 0

I tried checking for any whitespace in the yaml file but I didn't find any. I also tried changing the encoding of the file and validating the yaml file but nothing works.

Here is my yaml file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  python3.9

  Sample SAM Template for summarization-v2-lambda

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 30
    MemorySize: 3008

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        Root:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: get
        SummarizeAI:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /summarize_t5
            Method: post
        SummarizeArticle:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /summarize_article
            Method: post
        SummarizeTextRank:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /summarize_textrank
            Method: post
        SummarizeParagraphs:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /summarize_paragraphs
            Method: post
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./app
      DockerTag: python3.9-v1

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  RootApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Root route"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
  SummarizeAIApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/summarize_t5/"
  SummarizeArticleApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/summarize_article/"
  SummarizeTextRankApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/summarize_textrank/"
  SummarizeParagraphsApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod//summarize_paragraphs/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use this validation [link](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), this really helped me in fixing my indentation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).